# How i inject custom css and js files in my flutter webview from local asset folder

Tags: flutter

How i inject custom css and js files in my flutter webview from local asset folder
for eg :

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        try {
            console.log("onReady called...");
        } catch(err) {
            onError("Error in On Ready Function..! "+err.message);
        }
    });
</head>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `evalJavascript` function and inject CSS with JS code.

for example

````dart
var myJsCode = ```
   let linkElement = document.createElement('link');
   linkElement.setAttribute('rel', 'stylesheet');
   linkElement.setAttribute('type', 'text/css');
   linkElement.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/css;charset=UTF-8,' + encodeURIComponent('[url to css file]'));
```;

flutterWebviewPlugin.evalJavascript(myJsCode)
````

To load from the local asset folder, you can first read the file into a string and inject it in a similar way.

Comment: In my project we are using webview_flutter 0.3.15+1. Is it possible with this plugins??